# _mm_set_epi64x with valgrind reports as uninitialized

Tags: c++, valgrind, sse

I am having strange behavior with valgrind combined with the intrinsic `__m128i` when setting it with `_mm_set_epi64x()`. After i set the variable, valgrind reports it at uninitialized. The following is the offending code.

```
    for (u64 i = 0; i < mIndexArray.size(); ++i)
    {
        //reinterpret_cast<u64*>(&mIndexArray[i])[0] = mBlockIdx++;
        //reinterpret_cast<u64*>(&mIndexArray[i])[1] = 0;

        mIndexArray[i] = _mm_set_epi64x(mBlockIdx++, 0);
        Log::out << mIndexArray[i] << " ";
    }
```

`mIndexArray` is an `std::vector<__m128i>` of some size. Valgrind reports the last line of the loop as having `mIndexArray[i]` uninitialized. The commented code generates the same behavior.

Has anyone else experienced something similar?

`Log::out` is just some indirection for `std::cout`. And there is an overloaded function for `operator<<(ostream&, __m128i)`. The values that are printed are as expected, i.e. 00...000100...000 00...000200...000 ...

Thanks

Comment: Maybe try `__m128i _mm_cvtsi64_si128 (__int64 a)` to more directly tell the compiler you want to `movq` an integer into a vector register (zeroing the upper 64b).  Hopefully your real code processes data on the fly as it's generated, and this is just a MCVE that demonstrates the problem without any fluff.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but unfortunately that did not help. And about computing on the fly, the vector is short and then AES is called on it all. So its decently efficient i suppose.

Comment: Maybe just chalk it up to a false positive?

Comment: re: efficiency.  Yeah, probably not worth duplicating the code to use the AES intrinsics on the just-generated data, as long as the vector is significantly smaller than 32kiB (L1 cache size in Intel).  I think AMD Bulldozer-family only uses 16k L1 caches.  Re: valgrind: no clue, I haven't used valgrind myself.

Comment: Personally I would *not* use an array of `__m128i`. I would  an array of `u64` and then do `__m128i tmp =_mm_set_epi64x(mBlockIdx++, 0); _mm_storeu_si128((__m128i*)&mIndexArray[2*i], tmp)`. Though, I would never use `_mm_set_epi64x` in a critical loop.